# Ansible aws_secrets lookup bypath issue - returning only 10 elements

Tags: ansible, aws-secrets-manager

In my ansible playbook ( Ansible 2.10) I'm using lookup plugin to get all secrets from AWS Secrets Manager with the bypath attribute.

```
  vars:
    #which environment: dev, test,uat, prd
    my_env: dev
    aws_secret_path: mypath/{{my_env}}



  - name: "get all secrets from AWS Secrets Manager"
    set_fact:
      secret_value: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', '{{aws_secret_path}}', on_missing='skip', bypath='true', region='eu-west-1' )}}"
```

It is working fine however I realized that it returns only up to 10 elements. Is there a way to return all elements or use pagination ?

Thanks for help,
Greg

Comment: This wasn't what you asked, but nested jinja2 mustaches are always a bug: `secret_value: "{{ lookup('amazon.aws.aws_secret', aws_secret_path, on_missing='skip', bypath='true', region='eu-west-1' )}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/1.5.0/plugins/lookup/aws_secret.py#L196), it seems they are ignoring [the advice to honor NextToken](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.list_secrets), so you'll want to put that information in [your GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues/472) *(that you omitted from your question here)*.

Related to that: in the future, you'll want to include all of the helpful information you put into that GitHub issue when asking questions in the Stack Exchange network, too, since in both cases you're asking for help from some people who are not on your computer to know what you know